# Error when trying to apply Always Encrypted encryption on aspnet_Membership table

Tags: always-encrypted

I'm trying to encrypt the Email and LoweredEmail columns on a SQL database using Always Encrypted encryption using SSMS and I always get the same error:

> Lock request time out period exceeded. There is no user table matching the input name '[dbo].[aspnet_Membership]' in the current database or you do not have permission to access the table.
> I still get the same error when I log in as the SA account, sio I guess that it's not a permissions problem.

[image: SSMS select column]
[image: SSMS key]
[image: SSMS proceed]
[image: SSMS summery]
[image: SSMS error]

EDIT *** Added the PowerShell Script

## Generated by SQL Server Management Studio at 10:47 on 06/05/2021

Import-Module SqlServer

## Set up connection and database SMO objects

$password = ""
$sqlConnectionString = "Data Source=GALADRIEL\SKYLINE;Initial Catalog=SkylineMembership;User ID=sa;Password=$password;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Packet Size=4096;Application Name=`"Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio`""
$smoDatabase = Get-SqlDatabase -ConnectionString $sqlConnectionString

## If your encryption changes involve keys in Azure Key Vault, uncomment one of the lines below in order to authenticate:

## * Prompt for a username and password:

#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -Interactive

## * Enter a Client ID, Secret, and Tenant ID:

#Add-SqlAzureAuthenticationContext -ClientID '' -Secret '' -Tenant ''

## Change encryption schema

$encryptionChanges = @()

## Add changes for table [dbo].[aspnet_Membership]

$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName dbo.aspnet_Membership.Email -EncryptionType Deterministic -EncryptionKey "CEK_Auto1"
$encryptionChanges += New-SqlColumnEncryptionSettings -ColumnName dbo.aspnet_Membership.LoweredEmail -EncryptionType Deterministic -EncryptionKey "CEK_Auto1"

Set-SqlColumnEncryption -ColumnEncryptionSettings $encryptionChanges -InputObject $smoDatabase